# Module field type category not working

Tags: form-fields-types, custom-module, module-params, joomshopping

I am trying to tweak a module based on Joomshopping, a shopping cart extension.
The module is called "mod_jshopping_categories", I want to add a field that is a dropdown list of the product categories into the module's admin page. Here is what I added to the .xml file:

```
<field
  name="Parent Category"
  type="category"
  default="0"
  label="Parent Category"
  description="Put in category"
  extension="com_jshopping">
</field>
```

However, on the back end the dropdown list is empty. To test, I change "com_jshopping" to "com_content", the back end correctly shows a list of article categories.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Category_form_field_type)

> **type (mandatory)** must be category.
>
> **extension (mandatory)** is the name of the extension for which the
>   categories will be retrieved. For example, to list content categories,
>   use the value 'com_content'.

Does this mean there is no "category" in com_jshopping for the module to retrieve?

On the other hand, as a shopping cart extension, com_jshopping does have product categories. So how is this `category` defined programmatically?

Do I need to create a custom field type to retrieve com_jshopping's categories?

Answer (score 1):

Joomshopping may have categories for the products, but it does not the Joomla core categories table/model for its categories. It has its own.

The categories field is for the Joomla core categories, which means it will return categories that exist in the `#__categories` for the selected component/extension.

Note that `com_content` is not the only extension that uses the Joomla categories. For example, `com_contact` is another extension that uses them.

Regarding 3rd party components, they can also make use of them if using them would be a good fit or use their own approach to creating a categories feature.

You can create your own [**Custom Form Field**](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) that will list Joomshopping categories and use it in your **`XML`**, or maybe use the [**SQL field**](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/SQL_form_field_type) to query the database directly could be sufficient for your needs.

There is also a strong possibility that Joomshopping has already its own custom "Joomshopping Categories" field type defined somewhere that you can use.